# XSLT grouping: "Muenchian Method" vs for-each-group

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Our Java application uses XSL sheets for transforming XML into a 'suitable' XML. The problem is that the result XML is about 20000+ lines and it takes time to transform in Java (on production machine about 30 seconds).

This is not acceptable for business and I'm searching for ways to optimize my XSLT.

Currently I utilize XSLT 2.0 grouping:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="reportContent/transaction" group-by="transactionId">
```

One of our developers argues that this is the cause of the slow performance (and it is indeed. If I remove grouping, I get a 2X boost) and recommends using the **Muenchian method** for grouping.

Before I start to rewrite a lot of code I would like to find out if anybody else experienced something alike and rewriting grouping to **Muenchian method** gave performance improvements.

Comment: Why does replacing `<xsl:for-each-group select="reportContent/transaction" group-by="transactionId">` with Muenchian grouping require you to "rewrite a lot of code"? If you think that approach is faster then implement it and profile it to compare the results. Muenchian grouping is an XSLT 1.0 technique, I have doubts that an XSLT 2.0 processor in 2017 is not able to implement `for-each-group` in a comparable performance. As for boosting performance, you could look into commercial packages offering compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no intrinsic reason why Muenchian grouping should be faster than `<xsl:for-each-group>` (indeed there are reasons why in general one would expect it to be a bit slower). But with performance the devil is always in the detail, and certainly it's meaningless to ask questions about such performance comparisons except in the context of a specific XSLT 2.0 implementation.

30 seconds sounds very slow for this task and I would certainly suspect that improvements are possible. Ideally you should drill down to find where the time is going before you start any experimental tuning: for example, tools like Saxon's `-TP:profile.html` can be invaluable.